# iptables internal traffic redirection

Tags: proxy, iptables

I want to redirect all http/s traffic belonging to user 'cromy' to internal proxy:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m multiport -m owner --uid-owner cromy --sports 80,443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -s 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m multiport -m owner --uid-owner cromy --dports 80,443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Unfortunately it does not work, we have have respectively the following error messages:

```
[ 1317.240826] x_tables: ip_tables: REDIRECT target: used from hooks POSTROUTING, but only usable from PREROUTING/OUTPUT

[ 1265.161118] x_tables: ip_tables: owner match: used from hooks PREROUTING, but only valid from OUTPUT/POSTROUTING
```

Any idea folks? thanx.

Answer (score 0):

Based on very little information of what you are trying to achieve I guess you are looking for:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1 -p tcp -m multiport -m owner --uid-owner cromy --dports 80,443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8080
```

Please note that:

1. This will only redirect traffic to web server on IPv4 localhost address.
2. If you want to redirect all traffic to ports 80 & 443 just remove the -d option.
3. You can only match for user on the host itself, not on the router.
4. I don't know what you have listening on port 8080 so this is not guaranteed to work or may work only for one of the protocols.

Comment: @@Tomek: Thanx indeed but I am not sure to understand point 2. of your answer: My goal is: All internal (on my computer) traffic going to ports 80, 443 should first go through a sniffer on port 8080 (on my computer too), then leave my computer to go into internet to http/s servers. And all traffic coming from ports 80, 443 into my computer should first go through port 8080 then to my browser.